# VallidationAttribute check multiple values in a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-validation

I'm still new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm struggling with a validator I need to implement.

I have a `UserName` property in my `Account` model, that needs to be checked for uniqueness.
It's declared as followed:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameRequiredError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_LocalResources.Resources))]
[Display(Name = "UserName", ResourceType = typeof(App_LocalResources.Resources))]
[VallidateAccount(Field = AccountChecks.UserNameUnique, ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameUniqueError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_LocalResources.Resources))]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

The used ValidationAttribute has the following to perform the check

```
public class VallidateAccountAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public AccountChecks Field { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        switch (Field){
            case AccountChecks.UserNameUnique:
                return CheckUserName((string)value);
            //Other Fields
            default:
                throw new ParameterException("Invallid Field");
        }
    }

    private bool CheckUserName(string username)
    {
        Account account = Connection.DB.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username);
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && (account == null || account.AccountID == this.ID);
    }
    //Other checks
}
```

And now for the problem:
The entered username is correctly passed into the validation through the value parameter of the IsValid method, but I can't find a way to pass the ID along with it.

I've tried to pass it along the same way I pass the Field parameter, but I can't use the `this` keyword.

```
[VallidateAccount(Field = AccountChecks.UserNameUnique, ID = this.AccountID, ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameUniqueError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_LocalResources.Resources))]
```

Can anyone please help me in passing through the `ID` value?

### **EDIT: Implemented solution proposed by Rahul RJ**

Remote validation provided me with the ability to do exactly what I wanted.

The new `UserName` property:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameRequiredError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_LocalResources.Resources))]
[Display(Name = "UserName", ResourceType = typeof(App_LocalResources.Resources))]
[System.Web.Mvc.Remote("UserNameUnique", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "AccountID", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameUniqueError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_LocalResources.Resources))]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

The `ValidationAttribute` is no longer used in this case, instead it is replaced with a new `ValidationController`.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyProject.Models;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public class ValidationController : Controller
    {
        MyDbContext _repository;
        public ValidationController() : this(Connection.DB) { }

        public ValidationController(MyDbContext repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }
        //NOTE: Make sure the parameters have the same name as your properties!!!
        public JsonResult UserNameUnique(string UserName, int AccountID = 0)
        {
            Account account = Connection.DB.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == UserName);
            return Json(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) && (account == null || account.AccountID == AccountID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the Remote Side Validation in this Scenario.
with that you can easily check the Exsisting UserName.

Use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx  for your Reference

Comment: Thanks Rahul, after looking into remote validation. I found a way to do what I wanted. I've edited the original question with the adjusted code for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing to much! If you want to validate for uniqueness then just do that.

Where you have .FirstOrDefault you should change to .Any and just check to see if there is any rows with that username.

private bool CheckUserName(string username) {
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    return false;

return !Connection.DB.Accounts.Any(x => x.UserName == username);
}

Comment: The thing is, that would fail if an edit is done on an existing account. In that case the record would exists (it's the one you're updating) and it would return false. I need it to return true if this property doesn't change. It's allowed to change other values without changing the username, but it's also allowed to change the username, if the new value isn't in use yet. Hence the 2nd part of the or statement.